# Importing explicitly instantiated template class from dll

Tags: c++, dll, templates

Being a dll newbie I have to ask the allmighty SO about something.

Say I explicitly instantiate a template class like this:

```
template class __declspec(dllexport) B<int>;
```

How do I use import this templated class again?

I've tried the adding the code below in my .cpp file where I want to use B

```
template class __declspec(dllimport) B<int>;
```

Comment: "I've tried the adding the code below in my .cpp file where I want to use B " what have you found out? did you get errors? can you put it into your question what happened then?

Comment: probably `extern template class __declspec(dllimport) B<int>;` will do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you instantiate a template fully -- you have a complete type. It is no different from any other types. You need to include the header for `B` and also compile-time linking in with a `lib` file or dynamically load the dll to link to the definition.

Have you read this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168958 ?

Here's a brief summary of what I tested (and it worked):

---

**Create a dummy DLL project**

- Used the Win32 Console application wizard to generate the dll header/source files called: `template_export_test`
- Added the following:

file: `template_export_test.h`

---

```
#ifndef EXP_STL
#define EXP_STL
#endif 

#ifdef EXP_STL
#    define DECLSPECIFIER __declspec(dllexport)
#    define EXPIMP_TEMPLATE
#else
#    define DECLSPECIFIER __declspec(dllimport)
#    define EXPIMP_TEMPLATE extern
#endif

EXPIMP_TEMPLATE template class DECLSPECIFIER CdllTest<int>;
```

---

file: `template_export_test.cpp`

---

```
template<class T>
CdllTest<T>::CdllTest(T t)
: _t(t)
{
    std::cout << _t << ": init\n";
}
```

---

**Create the test application**

- Use the wizard to create a Win32 Console application called: `driver`
- Edit the Linker project settings of this project:

  - Add to Linker > General > Additional Library Directories: path to `template_export_test.lib`
  - Add to Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies: `template_export_test.lib`
- Include the `template_export_test.h` in the main cpp file

---

```
#include "c:\Documents and Settings\...\template_export_test.h"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    CdllTest<int> c(12);
}
```

---

- Compile and go!

Comment: I've tried :

extern template class __declspec(dllimport) B<int>; 

Didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  However, I think your sample doesn't work right. #ifndef EXP_STL #define EXP_STL is not right, and isn't consistent with the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, even with explicit instatiation of the template, problems may arise that lead to run-time errors. 
Take a look at [this interesting article to C4251](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/VisualStudio/warningC4251.html) (especially the "Conclusion").